# Improve image quality using python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

i have some problem with my task. i need get text from image using python+tesseract. But quality of image it's not highter - it`s screenshoot.

I'm using OpenCV lib and have two variant`s:

1. COLOR_BGR2GRAY
2. ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C | THRESH_BINARY

and this variant`s working incorrect.

When i binarize image

```
def binarize_image(img_path, threshold=195):
    """Binarize an image."""
    image_file = Image.open(img_path)
    image = image_file.convert('L')  # convert image to monochrome
    image = np.array(image)
    image = binarize_array(image, threshold)
    im = Image.fromarray(image)
    im.save(img_path)
    # imsave(target_path, image)
```

def binarize_array(numpy_array, threshold=250):
    """Binarize a numpy array."""
    for i in range(len(numpy_array)):
        for j in range(len(numpy_array[0])):
            if numpy_array[i][j] > threshold:
                numpy_array[i][j] = 255
            else:
                numpy_array[i][j] = 0
    return numpy_array

tesseract doesn`t usualy get text.

How i can resolve it`s problem ?

[screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLc4p.png)

UPD: solved my problem, i need to add some pixels between two letters. on screenshot letter is white and background is black. How i can do it using numpy ?

Comment: Can you upload a sample screenshot ?

Comment: @ZdaR, yes , sorry i forgot to do this

Comment: You should avoid iterating numpy arrays. You can achieve the same thresholding in a single line `thresholded = (numpy_array > threshold) * 255`. Additionally, be careful with the default values for the parameters, you have 2 functions with different default `threshold` values. It might be intentional, but if it is not it might introduce unexpected errors.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo, binarize method is not correctly to work

Comment: Your update is a totally separate problem. Regardless, to set the value of elements in a numpy array, simply [index them](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, Can i replace all pixels that are darker than the specified color to black ? i think it's will solve my problem because tesseract didn't get text through a small space between letters.

Comment: Of course! Let's say you have the array `A`. Then `A<4` will produce a boolean array the same size as `A`, but with `True` or `False` at each location on whether that element is `<4` or not. So this gives a boolean array that you can use for indexing (see the above link). So for example: `A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])`. Then `A[A<4] = 0` will set all values of `A` less than four to zero, that is, `A = np.array([0,0,0,4,5])`.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, thank you ;)